# Subbasis for an order topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm a little confused about how Munkres' defines subbasis for a topology. It says

> The topology generated by the subbasis $\mathcal{S}$ is defined to be the collection $\mathcal{T}$ of all unions of finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{S}$

So given a topology and a collection of sets, to show that the given collection is a subbasis for the topology, isn't it sufficient to show that the collection formed by taking finite intersections of elements of the given collection forms a basis for the topology?

But while proving that for an order topology, the subbasis is the collection of all open rays, Munkres does the following:

> Because the open rays are open in the order topology, the topology they generate is contained in the order topology. On the other hand, every basis element for
> the order topology equals a finite intersection of open rays; the interval $(a, b)$ equals
> the intersection of $(−\infty, b)$ and $(a, +\infty)$, while $[a_0, b)$ and $(a, b_0]$, if they exist, are
> themselves open rays. Hence the topology generated by the open rays contains the
> order topology.

I do not understand why the two-way proof is required. Isn't just showing that any possible finite intersections of the open rays will be basis elements for the order topology enough for the proof?

Comment: Instead of the open rays, consider the set of all subsets (i.e. the discrete topology). Then clearly every basis element equals a finite intersection of some of these sets, hence, the topology generated by this set as a subbasis contains the order topology. However, this topology is (in most cases) much larger than the order topology.

Comment: When you say "every basis element equals ..." do you mean the basis of the discrete topology, i.e., the discrete topology itself? If yes, then I think I've understood your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Munkres's argues in two steps:

1. Because the open rays are open in the order topology, **the topology they generate is contained in the order topology**.
2. Every basis element for the order topology equals a finite intersection of open rays; the interval $(a, b)$ equals the intersection of $(−\infty, b)$ and $(a, +\infty)$, while $[a_0, b)$ and $(a, b_0]$, if they exist, are
   themselves open rays. Hence **the topology generated by the open rays contains the order topology**.

You are right, one could alternatively argue that the set $\mathcal I$ of all finite intersections of open rays agrees  with the set $\mathcal B$ of intervals used as a basis for the order topology.

In step 2 Munkres proved $\mathcal B \subset \mathcal I$. But what about $\mathcal I \subset \mathcal B$? Either you brush it aside as "trivial" or you need a formal argument. This involves induction on the number of elements in the intersection and to consider a number of cases. I don't think this is easier than step 1.